# CSS selector for 2 of 4 classes

Tags: css

I have an element that has 4 classes. I want to select based on 2 of those classes but the CSS rule that I made for it does not apply in the browser:

It looks like

```
.one.two {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Can you also post an example of the html you're using?

Comment: Which browser(s)? All of them? Mutli-class selectors are not supported by IE6, but other than that it looks like you're doing it right.

Comment: Post your html. An element can have n number of classes and your selector can match on any combination of those classes in any order.

Comment: class = "one two three four" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample HTML/CSS of what you want:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .c1.c2 {
                background-color: #FFBBBB;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="c1 c2 c3">c1 c2 c3</div>
        <div class="c2">c2</div>
        <div class="c1">c1</div>
        <div class="c1 c2">c1 c2</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

It's working on Internet Explorer 8, Firefox 15, Chrome 21

Only first and last divs will get the red background, because only they are having c1 and c2 classes ...